# CPU Single Core : Need volatile or synchronized?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, volatile

In Java, Volatile and synchronized make multithreads can work together and understand each others as well. But, if you use multithread on single-core system, it mean not really multithread work, OS just changes from this thread to thread. (So, one variable just use ONE at exactly moment)

So, I think it not necessary to use safe-thread technique such as volatile or synchronized.
Does it true ?

thanks :)

Comment: What happens when you run your code on a computer with more than one CPU? It's always better to be safe than sorry.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Synchronization is independent of how many cores. It is based on how many threads competing for shared resource.  When more than one thread competing you need Synchronization.

Answer (score 6):

You are incorrect. Synchronization is still an issue on a single-core system, as the JRE may switch threads at any point (including while a thread is in a critical section).

Answer (score 1):

Synchronisation is important regardless of Single core or Multi core systems.In order to prevent Deadlocks,you need to correctly use Synchronisation.and besides Deadlock Prevention,Synchronisation is also essential in GUI applications where we need to compute intensive things in the background and periodically update GUI.